# Выборка элементов из вектора

Tags: c++, строки, vector

У меня есть текстовый файл, в котором написаны книги:

"война и мир" Толстой;

"горе от ума" Грибоедов;

"евгений онегин" Пушкин;

Где каждая строка это элемент в векторе.
И мне, например, надо чтобы остались только книги где есть слово война или автор Толстой:

"Война и мир" Толстой;

Как это реализовать через find и find_if?

Я должен сначала ввести имя(cin>>name), а потом уже использовать find?

Answer (score 1):

find (с векторами возвращает булевую переменную : false- если элемент не найден, true - если найден). Ваше предположение верно, вот как работает
find() : https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/ .

Примерно нужный вам код :

```css
string name;
cin>>name;
if(find(YourVector.begin(),YourVector.end(),name)==false)
{
    //производите удаление
}
```